# Android_Home is invalid according to appium-doctor

Tags: android, android-studio, appium, appium-android

In my Macbook, I have set my android home as shown below in the .bash_profile. However, I get an error message saying the path is invalid when I run appium-doctor.

I've verified that I can navigate to the path in both terminal and finder.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/cbellard/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/bin/java
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.9
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH=$M2:$PATH
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Here is the output from appium-doctor:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by replacing the exports in .bash_profile with identical (to human eyes) ones. So, I'm guessing at some point as I was copy-pasting some program changed one or more of the characters to an identical one.